# Querying for Multiple ManyToMany Fields

Tags: python, django

I have a model, `Entry`, with a `ManyToMany` field:

```
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

The `Tag` model is simple:

```
class Tag(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to create a function, `getEntryByTags` that takes a list of tag names and returns any Entry that has those tags. If I knew the number of tags and the names of each, this would be trivial:

```
Entry.objects.filter(tags__name="tech").filter(tags__name="music").filter(tags__name="other")
```

But since this is going to be based on user input and the tags number will be variable, I'm not sure how to proceed. How would I iterate over a multiple item list to get an object that contains each of the ManyToMany objects with the names represented in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

```
from django.db.models.query_utils import Q

tag_name_list = xxx # dynamic tag name list based on user input

query_list = [Q(tags__name=tag_name) for tag_name in tag_name_list]
query_set = Entry.objects
for query in query_list:
    query_set = query_set.filter(query)
return query_set
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just give me any object in a given list? So, in the example in my code, it would give me any object that has a tag named either music, tech, or other. What I want is for it to only give me objects with tags named music AND tech AND other.